# Restrict urls on certain apps in Django

Tags: django

I've looked for an approach to add specific urls to a certain app. And restrict the urls for being used on other apps in Django.

I use Mezzanine and when a user goes to sub.domain.com he will see templates that are specific to that site. But when the user tries to go to the url on sub.domain.com/example he will see the url that is intended to be on domain.com/example. I want that to be a 404 for the user instead on the app.

Sorry for my bad english, hope you understand what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current domain name (that the user is accessing) from `request.META['HTTP_HOST']`. Then based on that, raise 404 when the url is visited on certain domains.

```
from django.http import Http404
def my_restricted_view(request):
    domain = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
    if domain == 'sub.domain.com':
        return render(request, "template_name", {})
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: You could do a tiny bit more work and make this a decorator, e.g. `@restricted_view(optional_domain_list)`, and that moves all of the fiddly logic out of your views.

Comment: Good point, thanks! Yes, in reality, I would do that. I would probably store the subdomains and domains in database too.